# Is the given function Riemann Integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, riemann-integration

Consider $$f(x)=\begin{cases} 
       x^2  & x \in Q \\
      x^3 & x\in R-Q 
   \end{cases}$$
Is $f:[0,1] \rightarrow R$ Riemann Integrable?

---

My Attempt:

I tried defining a Partition $P=\{x_i: x_i = \frac in ;0\le i \le n\} $

Then I tried using Riemann Criterion of Integrability to try to prove that $L(P,f)=U(P,f)$.

However using the fact that $x^3<x^2$ in $[0,1]$.

The best I have gotten so far is showing that
$U(P,f)-L(P,f) \rightarrow 1/3-1/4 =1/12$

Comment: What you have shows that the function is not Reimann integrable,

Comment: But cant there exist another partition for which both sums are equal?

Comment: Riemann integrable functions are continuous almost everywhere. This function is not continuous at any point other than $0$.

Comment: No, however fine you make the partition between each $x_i, x_{i+1}$ we choose an $x_i^*.$  Since both the rationals and the irrationals are dense we can choose $x_i^*$ associated with either branch of the function.   The upper sums will be assoicated with $f(x) = x^2$ and the lower sum will be associated with $f(x)=x^3$

Comment: @DougM Is my attempt a complete proof?

Answer (score 1):

Given this partition $P_{n}=\{0,\frac{1}{n},...,\frac{n-1}{n},1\}$.

Here $||P_{n}||\to 0$.

So $\lim_{n\to\infty}L(P_{n},f)=\int_{\bar{a}}^{b}f$.

We have $$\inf_{x\in(\mathbb{R\setminus Q})\cap[\frac{i-1}{n},\frac{i}{n}]} x^{3}
=(\frac{(i-1)}{n})^{3}$$
But $$L(P_{n},f)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\frac{i-1}{n})^{3}\frac{1}{n}$$

So $$\int_{\bar{a}}^{b}f=\frac{1}{4}$$ by just summing and evaluating the limit. You can also do it by Riemann integrability of $x^{3}$ and convert summation to integral.

Similarly $$\sup_{x\in\mathbb{Q}\cap [\frac{i-1}{n},\frac{i}{n}]}x^{2}=(\frac{i}{n})^{2}$$

And hence $$\int_{a}^{\bar{b}}f=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n}(\frac{i}{n})^{2}=\frac{1}{3}$$

The inequality of the upper and lower Darboux sums show that the function is not Riemann integrable.

Comment: I would maybe denote the upper and lower integrals as $\underline{\int_a^b}$ and $\overline{\int_a^b}$ (`\underline{\int_a^b}` and `\overline{\int_a^b}`), rather than $\int_{\bar a}^b$ and $\int_a^{\bar b}$. It is, after all, the integration itself the bar is supposed to manipulate, not the bounds $a$ or $b$.

Comment: I'll edit it in. I was using the notation I am used to .